# Django REST Framework create/update 2 nested ForeignKeys

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, foreign-key-relationship

I'm trying to model a 2 nested ForeignKeys data structure like this, where the 'type' and 'source' fields are read_only.

```
[
    {
        "type": "web",
        "source_alerts": [
            {
                "source": "http://example.com",
                "alerts": [
                    {
                        "dns_server": "8.8.4.4",
                        "ip_addr": "213.229.190.11",
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "dns",
        "source_alerts": [
            {
                "source": "forinstance.com",
                "alerts": [
                    {
                        "dns_server": "8.8.8.8",
                        "ip_resolv": "213.152.6.144",
                    },
                    {
                        "dns_server": "9.9.8.8",
                        "ip_resolv": "228.48.14.74",
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "source": "okletsgo.uk",
                "alerts": [
                    {
                        "dns_server": "8.8.4.4",
                        "ip_resolv": "213.229.190.11",
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "source": "gocatgo.com",
                "alerts": [
                    {
                        "dns_server": "5.5.2.2",
                        "ip_resolv": "172.68.24.217",
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

What I'm trying to do is browse here: http://myapi.com/get_work//

and be able to POST something like:

```
{
    "type": "dns",
    "source_alerts": [
        {
            "source": "alehop.com",
            "alerts": [
                {
                    "dns_server": "8.8.4.4",
                    "ip_addr": "134.211.190.5",
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And only create the new 'alert' object associated to that 'source' and 'service'.

Could anyone recommend me which is the best way to do that?

I tryed to implement the create/update method in the serializers as in: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations with no success.

**---- % models.py % -----**

```
class Service(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField()
    entity = models.ForeignKey(Entity)

class Source(models.Model):
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, related_name='source_alerts')
    source = models.CharField(unique=True)

class Alert(models.Model):
    domain = models.ForeignKey(Source, related_name='alerts')
    dns_server = models.GenericIPAddressField()
    ip_addr = models.GenericIPAddressField()
```

**---- % routers.py % -----**

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'get_work', views.ServiceViewSet, base_name='get_work')

urlpatterns = patterns('app.views',
        url(r'^', include(router.urls))

)
```

**---- % viewsets.py % -----**

```
class ServiceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Service.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ServiceSerializer
    lookup_field = 'type'
```

**---- % serializers.py % -----**

```
class AlertSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = DNSAlert
        fields = ('dns_server', 'ip_addr')

class SourceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    alerts = AlertSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Source
        fields = ('source', 'alerts')

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        alert_data = validated_data.pop('alerts')
        alerts = instance.alerts
        instance.source = validated_data.get('source', instance.source)        
        instance.save()
        alerts.save()

        return instance

class ServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    source_alerts = SourceSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Service
        fields = ('type', 'source_alerts')
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Two problems here: 1) when you POST to 'get_work/' the router is directing you to the create(self, request) endpoint, when you are actually trying to do an update. 2) by marking 'source_alerts' as read_only the data is being stripped before any custom create/update method.

Comment: In order to do a proper update, you would ideally POST to the resource, so 'get_work/{id}' where id is the id of the Service you intend to update.

Comment: This {id} can't be the lookup field. Right?

There is a way to do something like: "get_work/{lookup_field=dns}/{id}/" ?

Thanks a lot for your answer @MarkGalloway.

Comment: In summary, when you POST to 'get_work/', the Service serializer is used in an attempt to create a new Service instance, but your provided nested JSON is stipped off before the serializers 'create' method because it is read-only. From the 'get_work/' URL (by default) you cannot update a Service instance as there is no service id provided. Take a look at Create and Update mixins here: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py. They correspond to the View methods that are being called create:'get_work/', update:'get_work/{id}'

Comment: In this case, the lookup is the id (or primary key). And I'm assuming this is a problem because you don't know the primary keys of the Service resources you're trying to update?

Comment: I don't know the pk of the Service resource. But I know the combination: (type, source_alert). Knowing the type and the source I can get the Service resource and update it, right? 
The problem is that I don't know which is the best way to access to that through the API.

Comment: Is type unique? Or can it be unique? If you want to use it as a lookup it would need to be unique.

Comment: It's unique for a given 'entity'. 
I'm so sorry because the model is very confusing.

Comment: The model makes sense. I think the only confusing part is the lack of 'id'. It's very difficult to perform an update on a Service without it, especially if the Service has no other unique field and also if different entities can have the same (type, source_alert) combination. In my opinion, the code you have is appropriate but it's the manner in the way you want to use it that is making things difficult.

Comment: How about using:

        unique_together = ("type", "entity")

on Service model?

Comment: If you are able to post the entity in the JSON, then you can create a custom View method which takes the type and entity and filters for the unique Service and then calls the serializer much like the UpdateModelMixin provided by the ModelViewSet. 

And again, you would need to remove the read_only field of the nested serializer. Additionally, you would need a custom update method in your serializer as I believe you intend to 'append' the new alert.